# Cause Layout get focus before its views

Tags: android, android-tv

I am developing an application for Android TV.
I have a layout which have horizontal LinearLayout (custom) which is used for navigation and below it a container for fragments.
What I want is when a user is focused on any item in the fragment (assuming that the fragment has only 1 row of views), when he clicks on UP on the D-Pad, the LinearLayout above it will get the focus and not the closest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.myApp.tv.view.categories.CategoriesLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_categoriesLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_contentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I really prefer not to interfere the fragment code.
Please give me your suggestions, thank you

Comment: could you explain bit more from where to which part you need to focus on up key ?

Comment: When the FrameLayout is focused and the user pressed UP key, I want the layout that above it to get the focus and not its children.